# Why do I get NullPointerException while adding elements to an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I want the user to input n numbers of his wish and write a program in java to find the average using arrays. I came up with the following program, but there seems to be a problem when i run it:
   `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at wert.main(wert.java:12)`

This is the code in question:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class wert {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int gucci[] = null; 
    System.out.print("Enter the length\n");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter the numbers : ");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

        int k = sc.nextInt();
        gucci[i] = k;
        }
    int m = average(gucci);
    System.out.println(m/n);

}
    public static int average(int x[]){
        int total = 0;
        for(int f: x){
            total =+ f;
        }
        return total;
    }   
}
```

I'm sorry if I am asking a really basic question. I started learning java on my own a few days back.

Comment: and the problem is... ?

Comment: @Mritunjay I have edited

Comment: here your array isn't initialized `gucci[] = null`, uses an ArrayList instead, I think we can't redefine the size of an array once initialized

Comment: You never set the size of the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem

```
int gucci[] = null;
```

Because the array is `null` the assignment fails With `NullPointerException`.

Change this part

```
int gucci[] = null;
System.out.print("Enter the length\n");
int n = sc.nextInt();
```

to

```
System.out.print("Enter the length\n");
int n = sc.nextInt();
int[] gucci = new int[n];
```

This will create an array of length you will enter.

Another problem is here

```
total =+ f;
```

If you want to add `total = total+f` it should be like below.

```
total += f;
```

Comment: Is there any problem with my logic in the program?i just ran it and I am not getting the average.

Comment: nevermind, i got it sorted. i typed =+ instead of +=. thanks alot @Mritunjay